# xor encryption code in c. but I can't understand specific line

Tags: c, encryption, kernel

[image]

Hi I'm a newbie in c Language and have a bad English.

I have a question.

```
int _len = len+24;
while(_len>0 || count%24){
    if(ind<24) msg[ind] = bytes[ind];
    else{
        msg[ind] = (_len>0?buf[ind-24]:'@')^msg[ind-24];
    }
    ++ind;
    --_len;
    ++count;
}
```

This is an encryption code.

but I can't understand 4th line in else.

I think just xor specific index of the array with -12 index.

My guess is right?

Figure1 is my purpose.

my code is suitable for Figure1?

please explain it to me.

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you get -12? In the code you use -24 and the figure shows 128 bits which is 16 bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite that statement to make it more obvious:

```
    msg[ind] = (_len>0?buf[ind-24]:'@')^msg[ind-24];
```

is same as

```
    char tmp;
    if (_len >0)
      tmp = buf[ind-24];
    else
      tmp = '@';

    msg[ind] = tmp ^ msg[ind-24];
```

Without more context I just have to assume a few things:

- `buf` seems to be a `char` array holding a message to be encrypted.
- `msg` is a `char` array used to store the encrypted message.
- `bytes` is probably an array holding the encryption key. This is also used to fill the first 24 bytes of `msg`.
- Each element of `msg` after the first 24 bytes is calculated by xor'ing the value from `buf` with the encrypted value we calculated 24 bytes earlier.
- If there are no more bytes in the input message, the loop continues up to a multiple of 24 iterations and now uses `'@'` as replacement for input message.

Basically, a key consisting of 24 characters is used to xor a given text. As the first 24 bytes seem to hold the key, there is nothing really secret about it. ;)

Comment: I want to xor key with the first 24bytes of the file and then repeat xor the result with the following 24bytes of the file until the end of the file. and that code is fit for my purpose?

Comment: Close, but not entirely true. Storing the key in first 24 bytes of output message is probably not what you want. You should replace `bytes[ind]` with `bytes[ind]^buf[ind]`.

Comment: from the above code, first 24bytes in msg[] is key and the remaining is fit my purpose, right? Thank you for your answer. It is really helpful to me

Comment: The last 24 bytes of the message are not encoded at all.

Comment: why?? I can't understand

Comment: sorry I modify my code. _len = len+24 is omitted in my code.

Comment: I make decryption code. can you feedback to my code?

Comment: What more feedback do you want? I think it is strange to store the key in the encoded array. But if you skipp these bytes it is OK. You have already fixed the missing 24 bytes at the end by increaind the length. Should work for you. If you don't face any specific problem, there is nothing more to tell.

Comment: Sorry If I am very good at English, I post my question with a more specific explanation about my code. Thank you for your advice. I will try to make a better question later. and I remove the key from msg buffer.